# Statistics Hypothesis test on a single sample

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm revising for my statistics exam that's coming up but I have a few questions without solutions in the book. I've worked out an answer however I'm not sure if it's correct. This question is:


In order for a clothes washer to qualify for ENERGY STAR, it must have
a Modified Energy Factor (MEF, a dimensionless quantity) of 1.42 or greater. Thirty-eight
Speed Queen commercial washers were selected at random, and the MEF for each was measured.
The sample mean was x = 1,228. Assume the distribution of MEF is normal and
σ = 0.5. Conduct a hypothesis test to determine whether there is any evidence the mean
MEF of this Speed Queen washer is less than 1.42. Use α = 0.01.


So my first step was to declare the variables from the question:

H0 = μ = 1.42

Ha = μ < 1.42

x̅ = 1.228

σ = 0.5

α = 0.01

Then I put that in the z score formula:

z = x̅ - H0 / (σ/sqrt(n))

z = 1.228 - 1.42 / (0.5/sqrt(38))

z = -2.367

Now I can look up the z table for a p value of p = 0.0091

 Then I conclude that I reject the null hypothesis because the p value is < than alpha the level of significance; 0.0091 < 0.01.

 Is this the correct answer/approach?

Comment: Your reasoning seems fine. The $p$-value is indeed smaller than the significance level implying to reject $H_0$. Hence, $\mu$ is significantly smaller than $1.42$.